# How to fix problem with AVAudioPlayer: "OpenFromDataSource failed"

Tags: ios, xcode, avaudioplayer

I'm working on Xcode 10.1 and this is a very basic snippet of an audio playing app.

```
var audioplayer:AVAudioPlayer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ringtone2", withExtension: "mp3")
    guard url != nil else{
        return
    }
    do{
        audioplayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
        audioplayer?.play()
    }
    catch{
        print("error")
    }
}
```

It should play the ringtone tune but the code enters the catch block and the following is printed:

> 2019-06-20 15:29:11.573735+0530 letsplaymusic[1539:42595] 1410:  Problem scanning for packets
>   2019-06-20 15:29:11.574033+0530 letsplaymusic[1539:42595] 1008:  MPEGAudioFile::OpenFromDataSource failed
>   2019-06-20 15:29:11.574204+0530 letsplaymusic[1539:42595] 101:  OpenFromDataSource failed
>   2019-06-20 15:29:11.574427+0530 letsplaymusic[1539:42595] 76:  Open failed
>   error

Comment: Change `print("error")` to `print(error)`.

Answer (score 0):

You might be placing your audio file at the wrong place. Try placing your file at the same hierarchy level as your `ViewController.swift` file.
I'm able to play the sound using the same code you posted, however I can't see where you have put the audio file so I'm guessing that must be the issue.

Comment: But under the Products file, [playmusicTests.xctest] and [playmusicUITests.xctest] are in red font. Is that a problem? How should I fix it? (the app's name is playmusic)

Answer (score 0):

**1. Make Sure .Mp3 file copy in Bundle and confirm with Log**

**2. player.prepareToPlay() - required function to play the resources**

```
func playAudioFile(_ url: URL) {
            print("playing \(url)")

            do {
                self.player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
                player.prepareToPlay()
                player.volume = 1.0
                player.play()
            } catch {
                self.player = nil
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                print("AVAudioPlayer init failed")
            }

}
```

Happy Coding... :)